# Failure to Psychopy GetKeys

Tags: python, psychopy

My task is to design a square block. It will run randomly from one side of the screen to the other. And a beep will be played sometime. One has to push the botton(Here is keyboard) as soon as he hears the beep. The question is, when I use the "getkeys" method, it always returns an empty list. The RT shows that it main get the very first input in the buffer. I also tried eventclear, but seemed useless.

Here is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from psychopy import visual, core, event,gui
from psychopy import sound as sd
#from psychopy.iohub.client.keyboard import Keyboard as kbd
import random, math,time
from psychopy.iohub import launchHubServer
import numpy as np

win = visual.Window(fullscr = False, size = [960,540], color = 'black', units = 'pix')

io = launchHubServer()

kbd = io.devices.keyboard

x,y = win.size

ran = [random.randint(-400,400),random.randint(-400,400),random.randint(-150,150),random.randint(-150,150)]

mode = random.randint(0,3)

start_pos = [[ran[mode],-269],[ran[mode],269],[-479,ran[mode]],[479,ran[mode]]]

rect = visual.Rect(win, width = 50, height = 50, fillColor='white', pos = start_pos[mode], name = 'target')

timer = core.Clock()

dx = [0,0,1,-1]
dy = [1,-1,0,0]

def present(rect,t):
    timer.reset()
    while timer.getTime() < t:
        rect.draw()
        win.flip()

    
def movement(rect,time):
    event.clearEvents()
    x,y = win.size
    timer.reset()
    timer_2 = core.Clock()
    timer_2.reset()
    jump = True
    while timer.getTime() < time and (abs(rect.pos[0])< x/2 and abs(rect.pos[1])< y/2):
        timeUse = timer_2.getTime()
        timer_2.reset()
        a,b = rect.pos
        rect.pos += [dx[mode]*timeUse*100,dy[mode]*timeUse*100]

        if int(timer.getTime()) == 3 :
            if jump :
                sd.Sound('D', octave = 5).play()
            #print("D" , timer.getTime())
            if jump :
                timer_jump = core.Clock()
                timer_jump.reset()
            print(timer_jump.getTime(),'++++++++++')
            event.clearEvents()
            if timer.getTime() < time and jump :
                print('============')
                #k_1 = event.getKeys(keyList = ['a','z'])
                while event.getKeys() is not None:
                    
                    RT = timer_jump.getTime()
                    print(RT,'--------')
                    break
                jump = False
        
        #print([timer.getTime(),time])
        #print(rect.pos)
        rect.draw()
        win.flip()


present(rect,1)
movement(rect,15)
```

I would feel my very gratitude to who helps.

Messhiro

Comment: @Michael MacAskill Maybe you can please help me a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is, when I use the "getkeys" method, it always returns an empty list.

`event.getKeys()` is an instantaneous check of the keyboard buffer. It will always return an empty list unless a key has been pressed since the last call to the function. So it is usually called in a loop, often once per screen refresh, to detect when a keypress has occurred. The result is that it will return an empty list many times, until a key is actually pressed.

But PsychoPy's `event` module has actually been deprecated in favour of the newer `Keyboard` class. This has the advantage that it returns the actual time that the key was pressed: when using `event.getKeys()`, one just infers the reaction time from the time that the function was called. This is some time after the key is pressed - even if you are calling the function on every screen refresh (typically at 60 Hz), this limits the time resolution to 16.7 ms. The `Keyboard` class, meanwhile, runs in a separate process and continually checks the keyboard hardware, allowing a precision more at the millisecond level.

Documentation on the `Keyboard` class is here: https://www.psychopy.org/api/hardware/keyboard.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I also tried keyboard class, the return remains empty list. I just copy the same codes from Documentation but it doesn't work@Michael MacAskill

Comment: This is going to require more to-and-fro than can be provided in the single question-and-answer format here at SO. I’d suggest you take this issue to the dedicated forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org for the kind of support you need.